# Can not trigger build with indication of "Not Run" in CircleCI

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

I am planning to migrate my existing CI to CircleCI 2 in favor of the docker. Once I tried to trigger a build it's shown something like this:

[image]

I also checked the steps as indicated in the below alert here https://circleci.com/sunset1-0/

> Service alert: Your project references CircleCI 1.0 or it has no
>   configuration. CircleCI 1.0 and projects without configuration files
>   are no longer supported. You must update your project to use CircleCI
>   2.0 configuration to continue. Learn more.

Is there anything I missed out?

Below is my .circleci/config.yml

```html
version: 2 # use CircleCI 2.0
jobs: # a collection of steps
  build: # runs not using Workflows must have a `build` job as entry point
    parallelism: 3 # run three instances of this job in parallel
    docker: # run the steps with Docker
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.4.2-jessie-node # ...with this image as the primary container; this is where all `steps` will run
        environment: # environment variables for primary container
          BUNDLE_JOBS: 3
          BUNDLE_RETRY: 3
          BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
          RAILS_ENV: test
      - image: mysql:5.7 # database image
        environment: # environment variables for database
          MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    steps: # a collection of executable commands
      - checkout # special step to check out source code to working directory

      - run:
          name: setup
          command: |
            curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash \
            && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
            && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
      - run:
          name: Dependencies
          command: |
            apt-get update && \
            DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
            build-essential mysql-client nodejs yarn && \
            apt-get clean && \
            rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*


      # Which version of bundler?
      - run:
          name: Which bundler?
          command: bundle -v

      # Restore bundle cache
      # Read about caching dependencies: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - rails-demo-bundle-v2-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
            - rails-demo-bundle-v2-

      - run: # Install Ruby dependencies
          name: Bundle Install
          command: bundle check --path vendor/bundle || bundle install --deployment

      # Store bundle cache for Ruby dependencies
      - save_cache:
          key: rails-demo-bundle-v2-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          paths:
            - vendor/bundle

      # Only necessary if app uses webpacker or yarn in some other way
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - rails-demo-yarn-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
            - rails-demo-yarn-

      - run:
          name: Yarn Install
          command: yarn install --cache-folder ~/.cache/yarn

      # Store yarn / webpacker cache
      - save_cache:
          key: rails-demo-yarn-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
          paths:
            - ~/.cache/yarn

      - run:
          name: Wait for DB
          command: dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:5432 -timeout 1m

      - run:
          name: Database setup
          command: bin/rails db:schema:load --trace

      - run:
          name: Run rspec in parallel
          command: |
            bundle exec rspec --profile 10 \
                              --format RspecJunitFormatter \
                              --out test_results/rspec.xml \
                              --format progress \
                              $(circleci tests glob "spec/**/*_spec.rb" | circleci tests split --split-by=timings)

      # Save test results for timing analysis
      - store_test_results: # Upload test results for display in Test Summary: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/collect-test-data/
          path: test_results
      # See https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/deployment-integrations/ for example deploy configs
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the build work, your config.yml file must live inside a .circle**ci** folder at the root of your project directory.

You post a very good description. Thanks for the code. The version config looks fine.  However, you wrote that your config currently lives at .circle/config.yml (Notice the missing **ci** at end of circle)

Move the config.yml to .circleci/config.yml and the build should proceed further. (right now the build is failing because **it has no configuration**.

E

Comment: Sorry for my typo, but I had it .circleci/config.yml

Comment: I created a minimal github project + circleci setup with the config you provided. Please see the repo here: https://github.com/ejparz/circle-test and first build here: https://circleci.com/gh/ejparz/circle-test/1. The build starts properly and does not display the 'Service alert' error from your question. What is the difference between my basic repo setup and yours? Is your repo public? Can you share a link to it and your circleci build dashboard?